# SetAttribute function not working as expected in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript

I was given an example from one of my classes that dynamically aligns a "div" element but it doesn't seem to be working in Chrome for some reason. The professor couldn't give me a valid reason as to why it was occurring. It works fine in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example: Getting Attributes</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr>
<div id="SetDiv" special_attribute="CIW rules!" align="left">
<p><h3>What are the attributes of this div tag?</h3></p>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="getValues()">
    <p><h3>Please click the button now</h3></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = null;
        function getValues()
        {
            if (div == null) 
            {
            div = document.getElementById("SetDiv");
            }
            alert(div.id);  
            alert(div.special_attribute);   
            alert(div.align);
     var align = document.getElementById("SetDiv").getAttribute("align"); 
      alert("getAttribute = " + align);
      var align = document.getElementById("SetDiv"); 
      align.setAttribute("align", "center");
      alert("setAttribute changes to center!");
      align.setAttribute("align", "right");
      alert("setAttribute changes to right!");
      align.setAttribute("align", "left");
      alert("setAttribute changes to left!");
         }   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is working as expected

Comment: The problem is that you are using `alert` and expecting a standardized behavior. You won't have it and should never ever use alert again. If you wish to log something, use [the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console).  `alert` will not only block js execution, but in some browsers (Chrome) it will also block the page's rendering. So you will have the impression that your code did nothing, which is one correct behavior, since you are overriding synchronously what you made before.

Comment: p.s. if you want to use the attribute correctly, try append `data-` in front of the attribute name to conform to HTML standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example: Getting Attributes</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr>
<div id="SetDiv" special_attribute="CIW rules!" align="left">
<p><h3>What are the attributes of this div tag?</h3></p>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me to move left!" onclick="moveMe('left')">
     <input type="button" value="Click Me to move center!" onclick="moveMe('center')">
      <input type="button" value="Click Me to move right!" onclick="moveMe('right')">
    <p><h3>Please click the button now</h3></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function moveMe(value) {
          document.getElementById("SetDiv").setAttribute("align",value);
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

basically you making change before dom changes are reflected back to page.